# Setting the Level of Python's Logger inside a Try/Except

Tags: python, logging, exception

I seem to be having a spot of trouble getting the logger set up in Python. I'm trying to read in values for the control of the program (oceanographic simulations, with a lot of little tuning factors which are best kept isolated in a file somewhere, as we tend to play around with them a fair bit) from a control file (JSON-based). Among these is the level to which the logging should be set. As this is something I expect people may misspell and Python is quite strict on, I'm trying to wrap the logger setup in a try-except which will default it back to INFO if there's a mistake (and give a warning), as shown:

```
with open(control['outFileStem'] + "_log.info", 'w'):
    pass #Clear an existing logfile
#Then set up the logging
try:
    logging.basicConfig(filename = control['outFileStem'] + "_log.info", level = control['logLevel'])
except ValueError:
    control['logLevel'] = "INFO"
    logging.basicConfig(filename = control['outFileStem'] + "_log.info", level = logging.INFO)
    logging.warning('WARNING: Logging Level set to INFO')

logging.info('Control structure created successfully')
```

However, when I experiment with it by mangling the level in the control file, it exclusively sets the level to WARNING. This happens no matter which variant I use for the level (i.e. logging.INFO, the numerical code, calling the value in from the control object as opposed to putting it in myself, etc.) I can't figure out what's going on here.

In case it's relevant, control is a dict to which I've altered the **init** method to handle the reading in from the JSON file nice and cleanly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `basicConfig()` (as documented) does nothing if handlers are already present on the root logger. The `basicConfig()` implementation sets handlers first and the level at the end, so if it fails at that point, handlers are already set and the `basicConfig()` call in the `except` clause does nothing. The simplest solution is, in the exception clause, to set the level using

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

instead of calling `basicConfig()` again to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define logLevel in control (what is it's type)?

What do you think of this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging

control = {"logLevel": "FAKE"}

# get log level object which is just a number
try:
    log_level = getattr(logging, control["logLevel"])
except AttributeError as ex:
    log_level = logging.INFO

logging.basicConfig(filename = "logfile", level = log_level)


logging.debug("debug test")
logging.info("info test")
logging.warn("warn test")
logging.error("error test")
```

Comment: I've tried using logLevel as a number, string (e.g. "INFO") and the logging.WHATEVER type. All 3 work fine in the Try:, none of them work in the Except:

Your suggestion works (thanks!) but I still don't see how my original snippet didn't...?

Comment: For me, logging.basicConfig does not complain about strange log levels. Are you sure the exception is getting triggered? I can't test it myself unless I see the config json file.  
  
  
For instance, this does not trigger an exception:
    logging.basicConfig(filename = "logfile", level = "broken")

Comment: It definitely does get triggered; I've dropped in some print() statements to check that. For me it's a ValueError if I try to pass it anything out of the ordinary. I'm using Python 3.4, perhaps it's a difference in the versions?

Comment: I am using 3.4. basicConfig (defined in /usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py on my machine) checks for root handlers before executing (if len(root.handlers) == 0).
  
  
What values make it fail?

Comment: It accepts the logging.FOO objects, numerical values (0,10,20,30,40,50) and the names of the levels (e.g. INFO) as strings. Anything else causes it to fail.